# How to set parameter path in JsonTypeInfo annotation?

Tags: polymorphism, jackson, parameter-passing

I am dealing with abstract and interfaces mapping with Jackson and i have this problem. I have this input:

```
data: {
    semaphore: {
        type: "MAIN",
        alertLevel: "NORMAL",
        ...
    },
    statusHolder: {
        ...
    {
}
```

So, having this class below, i want to make, by one side, that "semaphore" attribute from SemaphoreResponse class be converted into two different concrete classes (which both of them extends from AbstractSemaphore) depending "type" parameter from the input. And to do the transformation from the attribute semaphore to the concrete class i had no problem, because type attribute is inside object "semaphore", so i put this annotations inside AbstractSemaphore class and everything is all right

```
@JsonTypeInfo(  
    use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,  
    include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,  
    property = "type")  
@JsonSubTypes({  
    @Type(value = MainSemaphore.class, name = "MAIN"),  
    @Type(value = ExecutionSemaphore.class, name = "EXECUTION") })
```

So, here is my problem. I want to do a similar thing with statusHolder attribute. I have two concrete classes which extend from IStatusHolder (interface) and i want to make the convertion to the corresponding class depending "type" too, the same parameter as used before. The problem is that this parameter is inside "semaphore" object, outside from "statusHolder", so of some way i have to tell Jackson by an annotation to look for this attribute inside "semaphore" object and not from "statusHolder".

```
public class SemaphoreResponse {
    AbstractSemaphore semaphore;
    AbstractStatusHolder statusHolder;

    public SemaphoreResponse() {
        super();
    }

    // Getters and setters
}
```

Do you know how to do this? Thanks you from now

Comment: You should be able to annotate `IStatusHolder` like you did `AbstractSemaphone` using different names, of course. If `IStatusHolder` is an existing interface that you can't annotate, look into MixIn annotations. (http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonMixInAnnotations)

Comment: Sorry but i could not follow you. What do you mean by using different names?. I made a mistake, statusHolder is an Abstract class not an interface. Does it change anything?

Comment: By different names I mean that the name you use a shorthand for the class in your annotation `@Type(value = MainSemaphore.class, name = "MAIN")` has to be globally unique, unless you're using the `scope` property. It doesn't matter if it's `abstract class` or `interface`.

Comment: The problem is that the "type" parameter is not visible by ObjectMapper when it mapps statusHolder (type param is inside semaphore) so, if it try to look for it and it doesn't find it and throw a JsonMappingException. Is there any way to make this param globally for objectMapper or something like that? I appreciate your help

Comment: If you annotate `IStatusHolder`, serializing that object should also include the `@type` property. If you're saying that the type of `statusHolder` depends on the type of `semaphore`, that won't work. In that case, you should rethink the design since that kind of coupling is a bad idea. If you need it, you should consider encapsulating `statusHolder` into `semaphore`;

Comment: So there is no way to do that with this design? because i can't change the design because this is the mapping of the response from the service and my partner said that i had to respect the response arquitecture if i was mapping it. Do you know something that could help? I can't believe that there is no way to pass global parameters inside the object mapper!!. Thanks you!

Comment: The only thing I can think of would be to do a custom serializer for 'SemaphoneResponse' and encode both types in the wrapper. It get's a little ugly on coupling but it might work. I don't have enough information about your app to give you a definitive answer. Good luck.